# React Admin: Dynamic SuccessMessage in Create/Edit Views

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I am using the `react-admin` framework, and trying to send a dynamic `successMessage` from the `Create/Edit` views based on the value of a child input in the parent view's `SimpleForm`.

Right now `GetSuccessMsg()` is called once on render and is only passing the initial value to the notifications panel. Here's my current code.

```
export const UserCreation = ({ userId, timezone, ...props }) => {
  var SuccessMsg = "Account Created. Email sent to complete account setup."
  const ValidateUserCreation = (values) => {
    SuccessMsg = values 
      ? "Account Created. Email sent to complete account setup." 
      : "Account Created"
    return undefined
  };

  const GetSuccessMsg = () => { return SuccessMsg }

  return (
    <Create {...props} successMessage={GetSuccessMsg()}>
      <SimpleForm toolbar={<WithPracticeToolbar many />}>
        <TextInput source="name" />
        <TextInput source="phone" />
        <TextInput source="email" />
        <TimezoneDropDown source="timezone" />
        <BooleanInput
          validate={ValidateUserCreation}
          label="Create login account for this member"
          source="createMemberLogin"
          defaultValue
        />
      </SimpleForm>
     </Create>
   )
};
```

I am looking for any reasonable way to UPDATE the `successMessage` prop (passed to the `Create`) when the child input is changed.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `GetSuccessMsg()` is invoking the function right away, while `GetSuccessMsg` will only be triggered as and when required.

Answer (score 0):

you could try doing something like these. 
Furthemore think you will find details on https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html

```js
import { useForm } from 'react-final-form';

export const UserCreation = ({ userId, timezone, ...props }) => {

var SuccessMsg = "Account Created. Email sent to complete account setup."

const ValidateUserCreation = ({ formData, ...rest }) => {
    // here think you will hava acces to the formData values
    SuccessMsg = formData ? `Account Created. Email sent to ${formData.email} to complete account setup.` : "Account Created"
    return undefined
};

const GetSuccessMsg = () =>{
    return SuccessMsg 
}

return (
  <Create {...props} successMessage={GetSuccessMsg()}>
    <SimpleForm toolbar={<WithPracticeToolbar many />}>
      <FormDataConsumer>
        <TextInput source="name" />
        <TextInput source="phone" />
        <TextInput source="email" />
        <TimezoneDropDown source="timezone" />
        {formDataProps => (
          <BooleanInput
            validate={ValidateUserCreation(formDataProps)}
            label="Create login account for this member"
            source="createMemberLogin"
            defaultValue/>
         )}

      <FormDataConsumer>
    </SimpleForm>
  </Create>
)
};
```